# What's the cokernel of a monoid homomorphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra

Let $f:A\to B$ be a monoid homomorphism. Where can I find an explicit description of the its cokernel? Are there any books on this topic?

By the *cokernel* of $f$, I mean the universal arrow which postcomposes with $f$ to give the trivial homomorphism. (Sorry for not including this from the start, I just thought there's no risk of ambiguity.)

If anyone cares, here's my motivation. In the category of groups, the cokernel of the kernel of a group homomorphism $f$ is the quotient of the domain by the kernel, which is comprised of the cosets of the kernel. The first isomorphism theorem says this quotient is isomorphic to the image. This makes sense because the multiplicative kernel action has strongly connected components (because of the existence of inverses), so the cosets of the kernel are the fibers.

For monoids there's no first isomorphism theorem because the kernel is largely uninformative. However, some monoid epimorphisms are known to be the cokernels of their kernels (namely Schreier split monoid epimorphisms), and I would like to see what this means concretely.

Comment: I am not sure what you want here. There is a first isomorphism theorem but one uses congruences not kernels. I don't think any reasonable extension of group extension theory exists for monoids. Things like cohomology seem to work for only very special extensions. Leech's theory seems the best of these.

Comment: I want an explicit description of the cokernel of a monoid homomorphism. My motivation is to understand Schreier split epimorphisms. In my opinion "the first isomorphism theorem" is the statement that the kernel determines the image, not the kernel pair. There are other isomorphisms of interest between different notions of image. For instance in an algebraic category, the coequalizer of the kernel pair coincides with the set-theoretical image iff the category is balanced, but this is not what I'm after. I just want to understand cokernels.

Comment: I assume you want something more informative than "it is the quotient of B by the image of A". But even in the category of groups is there more you can say universally?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd in the category of groups I understand what quotients mean and how they look like - their elements are cosets. But what does quotient mean for monoids? You can use internal equivalence relations as mentioned in a previous comment, but I'm not sure how to find the cokernel that way.

Comment: What universal property do you want a cokernel to have?

Comment: A reformulation of the comment by @BenjaminSteinberg about the desired universal property: What is the definition of "cokernel" in the context of monoid homomorphisms? I would guess that it should mean the coequalizer of the given homomorphism and the constant homomorphism that sends everything to the identity. But it would be good if you'd confirm or correct that guess.

Comment: @AndreasBlass that's exactly right. (Sorry for taking a while to reply.)

Comment: I really wonder about that confusion here and why Arrow feels "sorry" for not giving the definition. This definition is standard. Cokernels are defined unambigiously in any pointed category (see Mac Lane or nlab or Wikipedia) and monoids form a pointed category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the construction is as for all (pointed) algebraic structures. Let $\sim$ be the congruence relation generated by $f(a) \sim 1$ for $a \in A$. Here, congruence relation means an equivalence relation on the underlying set of $B$ satisfying $b \sim b' \Rightarrow x b \sim x b' \wedge  b x \sim b' x$ for all $b,b',x \in B$. Then $\mathrm{coker}(f)$ is the quotient monoid $B/{\sim}$, i.e. the set of equivalene classes of $\sim$ equipped with the monoid structure which is uniquely determined by the property that $B \to B/{\sim}$, $b \mapsto [b]$ is a homomorphism.

It remains to give an explicit description of $\sim$. In the commutative case (more generally, when $f:A \to B$ is central), we have the following:

$b \sim b' \Longleftrightarrow \exists a,a' \in A ( f(a) b = f(a') b')$

In the non-commutative case, the description is much more complicated. You basically have to work with chains of relations and longer products as in the general description of generated congruences. More explicitly, $\sim$ is the transitive closure of the following relation:

$b \approx b' \Longleftrightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \, \exists a_i,a'_i,c_i,c'_i \in A \, \exists b_i,b'_i \in B: \\ b = b_1 f(a_1) \dotsc b_n f(a_n), ~  b' = b'_1 f(a'_1) \dotsc b'_n f(a'_n),\\ b_1 f(c_1) \dotsc b_n f(c_n) = b'_1 f(c'_1) \dotsc b'_n f(c'_n).$

That being said, it should be pretty clear that you are lost when you want (or have) to use elements instead of the universal property.

Let me mention that the Grothendieck group resp. the universal enveloping group (this is what it's sometimes called in the non-commutative case) of a monoid $A$ is just the cokernel of the diagonal $A \to A \times A$.

Comment: Given the OP was unhappy with the first isomorphism theorem via equivalence relations it wasn't clear this is what the op wanted.